# Link em portagens

Tags: php, html5

Eu tô pegando textos do meu banco de dados, eu queria saber, se existir algum link dentro desse texto, como faço para  ele aparecer como um link normal pra todo mundo?

Comment: São duas questões:  "eu queria saber, se existir algum link dentro desse texto" Você não consegue visualizar? Segunda:  "como faço para ele aparecer como um link normal" Para saber se existe link. Basta visualizar o texto. O link dentro de um texto X, pode vir das seguintes formas: http:// www ou <a href="http://". Seria mais ou menos o que você quer? Há tags html? Se sim, edite sua pergunta e insira os blocos de texto/código.

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente você vai precisar efetuar um replace

#### Expressão regular

```
~[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]~
```

#### Implementação no PHP

```
$texto = "Oi, sou Mauro, costumo acessar vários sites como http://www.facebook.com";

$texto = preg_replace(
    "~[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]~", 
    "<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>", $texto
);

echo $texto;
```

Veja em funcionamento: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/15e9d2a36e35ef396e4fd54fbdb4efaffa68890d

### Bibliotecas

Caso não queira reinventar a roda, há algumas `libs` que fazem esse trabalho para você, essas são as que uso/usei e recomendo.

[misd-service-development/php-linkify](https://github.com/misd-service-development/php-linkify)

[Jasny - Gist](https://gist.github.com/jasny/2000705)